# Calling REST Controller from maven dependency

Tags: spring-boot, maven, dependencies, spring-restcontroller

Suppose I have a `SpringBoot 2.2.6` WebApp calls *app-client* and a *Maven module* calls *common-crud* where I need to insert some commons Controller. For just an example suppose that the *common-crud* has just a package with just the follow Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/sayHelloFromModule")
public ResponseEntity<String> sayHello() {
  return new ResonseEntity<String>("Hello", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

the `.pom.xml` of the *common-crud* maven module is as follows:

```
<project..
  <groupId>com.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>common-crud</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>common-crud</name>

  <properties>
   ...
  </properties>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The `app-client` is a SpringBoot app and have it's main and so on.. the `.pom.xml` is:

```
<project..
  <groupId>com.mainapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>app-client</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>app-client</name>

  <properties>
   ...
  </properties>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>com.common</groupId>
     <artifactId>common-crud</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

The *main-app* is deployed on external Tomcat 8.5.53 with contextRoot mainapp. Now if I open a browser and call:

```
http://localhost:8080/app-client/<some-controller-inside-mainapp>
```

It clearly works with no problem.. if I call:

```
http://localhost:8080/app-client/sayHelloFromModule
```

throws me `Error 404`. I don't know if I can realize it in some ways or it is just a bad practice and cannot work in any circumstances.

Clearly the real scenario is more complex.. and the library module should use to profile different type of `SpringSecurity` Authentication (SAML, JWT, Oauth2.. and so on).

Is there a way to achieve this??
Thank you

Comment: you forget / like this "/sayHelloFromModule"

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it's clearly a digit error...

Comment: Not sure about it but worth trying, can you please check if you have provided any context path in the properties file that might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than they appear. In the `Main` class of `mainapp`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({
  "com.client.oauth",
  "com.client.resources",
  "com.client.security.config",
  "com.auth0.core.common",
  "com.auth0.core.provider"
})
public class OauthClientApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {}
```

the dependencies packages should be imported